# Returning a String from a SQL query in MVC Entity Framework 6 Controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to execute a basic SQL query (e.g. "SELECT string FROM table WHERE criteria = TRUE) on MVC Entity Framework 6. The returned type is to be a string. I have tried many possible things but they return the SQL query string or something completely irrelevant, such as:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Fname] AS [Fname] 
FROM [dbo].[Developer] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE ([Extent1].[Login] = @p__linq__0) 
   OR (([Extent1].[Login] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

I have the following in my controller:

```
var data = db.Developers.Where(y => y.Login.Equals(username)).ToList();
```

This is my `Developers` class:

```
public partial class Developer
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Fname
    {
        get { return Fname.ToString(); }
        set { Fname = value;}
    }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Developer1 { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsManager { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsPF { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsLW { get; set; }
    public string Prov { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the string that this query returns.

Somehow this works when this is made to a List and passed to the View model, where it is displayed using `@Html.DisplayFor()`.

Is there a way to execute my SQL command in my controller and get a string value in return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirstOrDefault() to return the first element, in this case there is only one.

You should include a validation if username doesnt exist.

```
Developer myDeveloper = db.Developers
                         .Where(y => y.Login.Equals(username))
                         .ToList()
                         .FirstOrDefault();

return myDeveloper.Lname;
```